# Are these two form of "I live in..." both correct? 我在意大利住 and 我住在意大利

Tags: mandarin, expressions, verbs

While studying I came across a useful expression to say "I live in..." which is "...在...住" such as in this sentence:

> 我**在**意大利**住**。= *I live in Italy.*
>   <sub>Wǒ **zài** Yìdàlì **zhù**.</sub>

But then I saw a different one which is:

> 我**住在**意大利。
>   <sub>Wǒ **zhù zài** Yìdàlì.</sub>

My questions are: Are both expressions correct? If so, are there any differences in usage and meaning? Is one of them more used currently?

Comment: Different structure. The position of adverbial 在意大利 locate between **subject** and **verb** in Chinese, just like the adverbial 周日 in **我**周日**回来**, in English it appears at end of the sentence. But in 我住在意大利, 住在 like a verb but not an adverbial, you can also speak 我住意大利, but you can't speak 我意大利住.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They both make sense but the 2nd one is used more commonly in Mandarin Chinese while the 1st one is used more often in Cantonese Chinese.

Comment: Thank you Desmond. A short question: If I used the first one speaking Mandarin, would it be seen normal by native speakers or would I get weird looks? :D

Comment: Hi Alenanno, sorry for the late reply. Native Mandarin Chinese will understand when you say that, therefore you won't get weird looks, but you may spot a couple seconds of pondering on their face. Just try to avoid it and use the 2nd one if you can. : )

Comment: No problem. :) I have "moved" to the second one, so now I always use that. :)

Answer (score 5):

I actually think these two sentences are slightly different. The first sentence has its emphasis on "住", for example, in the context "我不在上海上学，我在上海住。”

The second sentence has its focus on the residing place. For example, the context is 他住在哪里？他住在上海。

According to the context, you decide which sentence to use.

Comment: Would it sound unnatural to answer the question 你住在哪里 with 我在加拿大住?

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct.

Currently I cannot think of any difference, or if any of them is preferred in usage. Hope others can catch that.